# SessionFactory not creating using hibernate5.1.4 and spring 4.3.4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am creating a simple add to database using spring 4.3.4 and hibernate 5.1.4 but sessionfactory object is not creating and throughing NullPointerException.
Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.dao.AdminDao.addAdmin(AdminDao.java:39)
at com.controller.Controller.main(Controller.java:19)
```

Here is the code

bean.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">  

<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.data"></context:component-scan>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dao"></context:component-scan>

<bean id="data" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/appointmentportal" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="data"></property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.data"></property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect" >org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Model Class

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_admin")
public class Admin {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="admin_id")
int id;
@Column(name="admin_name")
String name;
@Column(name="admin_email")
String email;
@Column(name="admin_address")
String address;
@Column(name="admin_password")
String password;
@Column(name="admin_age")
int age;
// setters and getter
}
```

AdminDao class

```
@Repository
public class AdminDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void addAdmin(Admin admin){
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(admin);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Main method class

```
public class Controller {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Admin admin = new Admin();
    admin.setAddress("asda");
    admin.setAge(12);
    admin.setEmail("fgggg");
    admin.setName("eee");
    admin.setPassword("123");
    AdminDao adminDao = new AdminDao();
    adminDao.addAdmin(admin);
}
}
```

Comment: And why should spring inject something in a bean you are creating yourself? You are doing `new AdminDao()` instead of auto wiring the Spring configured instance... Your `Controller` doesn't even use Spring to bootstrap the application.

Comment: As @M.Deinum stated you manually create the AdminDao/ You should get the bean from SpringContext instead

Comment: You must use `@Autowired` annotation instead of making new instance of AdminDAO . And  You can achieve this by  constructor or setter methods  for autowiring.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Controller {
@Autowired
AdminDao adminDao ;
```

And use only adminDao for transaction intead of `AdminDao adminDao = new AdminDao();`

```
adminDao.addAdmin(admin);
```

Hope this will work .